# How do I add a wireless printer?

Tags: macos, printing

This seems pretty easy in Windows 7, but I am unsure of how I can do this on Mac OS X. I have a Wireless printer connected to my router via Wireless, and now I want to use it with my Mac. How can I connect to the wireless printer with my Mac? I am using OS X Lion and am on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the wireless printer has joined the network, OS X should see it listed as a nearby printer. From the Print & Scan pane in System Preferences, click the Plus (`+`) button in the lower left, and it should show up in the popup menu. 
[image: Print and Scan screenshot]

If it doesn't, select "Add Other Printer or Scanner…" In the resulting window, the "Default" Tab will show all local Bonjour printers, as well as any connected directly via USB. If you know the local IP of the printer you want to add, you can enter this in the IP tab.